# issue with react-native: start script 'react-native-scripts start'

Tags: node.js, facebook, reactjs, react-native

I'm using node v6.11.3, npm version 3.10.10
and create-react-native-app version: 1.0.0, macOS Sierra 10.12.6
When I tried to follow the instructions I found here:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#content to create a minimal react-native app, I received the following error

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@3.10.10
3 info using node@v6.11.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle AwesomeProject@0.1.0~prestart: AwesomeProject@0.1.0
6 silly lifecycle AwesomeProject@0.1.0~prestart: no script for prestart, continuing
7 info lifecycle AwesomeProject@0.1.0~start: AwesomeProject@0.1.0
8 verbose lifecycle AwesomeProject@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle AwesomeProject@0.1.0~start: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/Users/alejandro.caballero/Projects/AwesomeProject/node_modules/.bin:/Users/alejandro.caballero/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin:/Users/alejandro.caballero/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/bin:/Users/alejandro.caballero/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin:/Users/alejandro.caballero/.jenv/shims:/Users/alejandro.caballero/.jenv/bin:/Users/alejandro.caballero/.jenv/shims:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/usr/local/munki:/Library/TeX/texbin:/Users/alejandro.caballero/.rvm/bin
10 verbose lifecycle AwesomeProject@0.1.0~start: CWD: /Users/alejandro.caballero/Projects/AwesomeProject
11 silly lifecycle AwesomeProject@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'react-native-scripts start' ]
12 silly lifecycle AwesomeProject@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle AwesomeProject@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
14 verbose stack Error: AwesomeProject@0.1.0 start: `react-native-scripts start`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:255:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:920:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:230:5)
15 verbose pkgid AwesomeProject@0.1.0
16 verbose cwd /Users/alejandro.caballero/Projects/AwesomeProject
17 error Darwin 16.7.0
18 error argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
19 error node v6.11.3
20 error npm  v3.10.10
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error AwesomeProject@0.1.0 start: `react-native-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the AwesomeProject@0.1.0 start script 'react-native-scripts start'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the AwesomeProject package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     react-native-scripts start
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs AwesomeProject
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls AwesomeProject
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I already have tried uninstall node and install it again and nothing

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below commands in terminal, May be it will helps you.

- brew uninstall node
- sudo chown -R "$USER":admin /usr/local
- sudo chown -R "$USER":admin /Library/Caches/Homebrew
- brew install node
- npm install -g create-react-native-app
- create-react-native-app Your_Project_Name
- cd Your_Project_Name
- npm start

If above commands not work for you then once try below command and repeat all above commands again.

- ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"